# How can I create Jar files for only changed source automatically

Tags: java, ant

I have a project where there are hundreds of jar files, which mostly are for different modules and some are utilities used by many modules. I use ANT to build the project. I am looking for a way where if I made code change in two modules, ANT can identify and create only two jar files for me so that I can create kind of a patch and drop two jars to the application. ANT is loading source for Microsoft Team foundation server.

Comment: This seems like it will only cut down on the size of the deployment package you need to transfer, and unless it is truly gigantic as a complete package, it seems rather silly to worry about. IMHO a deployment package should contain everything it needs to run.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Let me be more specific about the issue. I have a client app which updates itself with the jars on server with higher version. If I deploy all the jar files client update module ask users to download all the jar files and download size becomes huge while If it was only one jar it could have been less than 1mb. If there is a way to not increase version in jar if source is not changed then deploying whole package on server is not an issue. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't know about that in ANT, I use Maven. Our projects are independently set up as projects unto themselves. Each is then deployed to an archiva repo for reference in a POM. When we have your issue, we still deploy the entire application, as its still a reasonable size. But if we didn't want to, we would still at minimum have to deploy the application, and the update dependencies (not necessarily all of the deps), because the manifest of the app would change to reflect the new version of the dependency. Perhaps you can do this in ant, butI dont know. I wish you luck!